# Lax pair for discrete integrable systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrable-systems

The Ablowitz-Ladik system is written as $i\dot{u}_n = (1+|u_n|^2)(u_{n+1} + u_{n-1})$ and is completely integrable. To my understanding, such integrable systems always have a so-called Lax Pair, but I cannot find what it is in literature. Do discrete integrable systems have these?

Comment: This paper gives a Lax pair and a Lax matrix https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.04866.pdf

Comment: Thanks. It seems, page $4$, constructing Lax pairs is not a trivial task.